# Asp.net core module does not connect to Azure IOT Edge Hub

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to connect an ASP.NET Core edge module to the edge run time hub(local) but it does not connect and fails with an CONNECT failed: RefusedNotAuthorized exception. I have standard .net core modules which connect to the edge hub and publish messages but the ASP.NET core edge module does not. Both the .net core and asp.net core edge modules are pushed from the Azure IOT Edge portal.

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the DeviceClient and sets up the callback to receive
    /// messages containing temperature information
    /// </summary>
    static async Task Init(string connectionString, bool bypassCertVerification = false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Connection String {0}", connectionString);

        MqttTransportSettings mqttSetting = new MqttTransportSettings(Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt_Tcp_Only);
        // During dev you might want to bypass the cert verification. It is highly recommended to verify certs systematically in production
        if (bypassCertVerification)
        {
            mqttSetting.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        }
        ITransportSettings[] settings = { mqttSetting };

        try
        {
            // Open a connection to the Edge runtime
            DeviceClient ioTHubModuleClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, settings);
            await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " IoT Hub module client initialized.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this issue with the code you provided,it works.I think you need to check the connection string of the device.
If you connect the device client with an incorrect connection string, the error `CONNECT failed: RefusedNotAuthorized` will occur. You can copy the connection string from Azure Portal(IoT Edge->->Connection string primary key).

Comment: Have you tested this in a ASP.NET Core module? Remember the ConnectionString is provided by the Edge runtime in the environment variable and Im not hardcoding it

Comment: If working on ASP.NET Core module, can you please provide the sample project in github?

Comment: The issue was with not using the preview version of the Microsoft.Azure.Device.Client framework. When adding thorugh Nuget package manager the checkbox has to be checked to load preview versions

Answer (score 0):

There are two authorizations need by a module at this time.  One is the connection string, which will enable the module to connect to IoTHub, but we have a server certificate on the edgeHub to establish a connection to the edgeHub.  That certificate is passed to the module via the filesystem and an environment variable establishing the path to the file.

Do you have the "InstallCert()" function in your module, and is it being called?

```
        static void InstallCert()
    {
        string certPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EdgeModuleCACertificateFile");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certPath))
        {
            // We cannot proceed further without a proper cert file
            Console.WriteLine($"Missing path to certificate collection file: {certPath}");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing path to certificate file.");
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(certPath))
        {
            // We cannot proceed further without a proper cert file
            Console.WriteLine($"Missing path to certificate collection file: {certPath}");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing certificate file.");
        }
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(certPath)));
        Console.WriteLine("Added Cert: " + certPath);
        store.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I have the method but as the comment in the default template says its not doing the install of the certificate in windows. I added log messages and its not called even in my other .net core modules and it still connects.( I believe the cert is for validating hte TLS connection and we are hardcoding the validation to true now)